# SQL Server admin: 1 user belong to 2 user group permission conflict

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a question regarding 1 user belongs to 2 different user group in SQL Server and I am trying to manage object permission in the server.

In our database, there is one view with sensitive permission that only certain people can see it, and most of our user are manage in the group.

such as: Sales Group, Manager Group

Ideally, we want only grant permission to Manager Group and deny permission to all the other user,

Let's say manager John is in Manager group, but he is also in Sales Group since he is the manager in Sales department.

My understanding is, if 1 user in 2 different user group, if you deny permission to any of the group, even the user have granted permission in another, he can still not see the object.

How can I overcome this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replying my own question, we found the solution,

under database security, we can create database role, in database role we can assign single table permission to different role, then we assign database role to user group. in this case, ex.

there are 3 table in the database, 
table A is the one with credential information. only manager can see
Table B and C is just the regular table.

create database role 'Normal Access' and grant permission to table B and C.
Then create another database role 'credential Access' and grant permission to table A.

in your Server level security. all the user group should only belong to 'Public', in Server roles level.

and in Use mapping, select the database and only choose the database role you assign.

in my case, Assign database role, 'Normal Access' and 'Credential Access' to Manager group.  so he will have all the access to ABC table

Sales Group should only have 'Normal Access' so it cannot access A table.

thanks